# Nestable / sortable serialized list without removing the original item from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been using the Nestable JS from Bushell (https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) for a while and have lots of usable code to generate the menus from Mysql, but I need to drag available options from one list to another list without removing it from the source.

I just want to append it to the list second list. Is this reasonable to do with Nestable or do I need to run back to jquery draggable to get the "clone" option?
Demo I found to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Aub7x/

On this demo it would be easy enough, except when you use `$( ".items" ).sortable( "toArray" );` it doesn't return the nested format that I can use to identify parent child relationships. Otherwise it is a much cleaner code base to work off of than the Bushell library.
http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/6CDSB/1/

Since I am linking to JSFiddle, it requires some code to be posted. In the Bushell code I was working hard to find where items were removed from the source, but didn't see it here:

```
list.el.on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    if (list.dragEl) {
        return;
    }
    var target = $(e.currentTarget),
        action = target.data('action'),
        item   = target.parent(list.options.itemNodeName);
    if (action === 'collapse') {
        list.collapseItem(item);
    }
    if (action === 'expand') {
        list.expandItem(item);
    }
});

var onStartEvent = function(e)
{
    var handle = $(e.target);

    /* callback for beforeDragStart */
    list.el.trigger('beforeDragStart', [handle]);

    if (!handle.hasClass(list.options.handleClass)) {
        if (handle.closest('.' + list.options.noDragClass).length) {
            return;
        }
        handle = handle.closest('.' + list.options.handleClass);
    }

    if (!handle.length || list.dragEl) {
        return;
    }

    list.isTouch = /^touch/.test(e.type);
    if (list.isTouch && e.touches.length !== 1) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    list.dragStart(e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e);

    /* callback for dragStart */
    var item = list.dragEl.find('.'+list.options.itemClass);
    list.dragRootEl.trigger('dragStart', [
        item,           // List item
        list.el        // Source list
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution here: https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable/issues/158

You can add the class of "clone" to anything you want to drag from one list to the other.

Put this around line 325:

```
if ($(dragItem[0]).hasClass("clone"))
{
    var cln=dragItem[0].cloneNode(true);
    dragItem[0].parentNode.replaceChild(cln, dragItem[0]);
    $(dragItem[0]).removeClass("clone")
    dragItem.after(this.placeEl);
}else{
    dragItem.after(this.placeEl);
    dragItem[0].parentNode.removeChild(dragItem[0]);
}
```